# Add Scroll to Side of DataTable (Package DT)

Tags: javascript, r, r-markdown, dt, flexdashboard

I have a created a flexdashboard through RMarkdown. In my Rmarkdown document I wanted to add a `datatable` from the package `DT` which would be able to have your table interactive. The issue I am having is that when I create this, there is no scroll bar on the side to scroll up and down the table. I know I need to implement javascript which is provided in this link but I am not sure how to implement javascript with RMarkdown: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_xy.html

I attempted scrollY but when I do that the header alignment is completely off.

The sample code for this is below and completely reproducible because I am also using the `mtcars` dataset.

````
---
title: "Morning Reportab"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
```

Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### AGORA {data-height=170}

```{r}
datatable(mtcars)
```

Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------


### Chart B {data-height=170}

```{r}
datatable(mtcars)
```

Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------


### Chart C

```{r}
datatable(mtcars)
```
````

This is the output screenshot: 
[image]

How do I add a scroll bar on the side of each table in this rmarkdown?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Using `DT 0.2` i got scrollbars by default. Check the option `options(DT.fillContainer = T)`

Comment: Hi @MartinSchmelzer thanks for the feedback. I added that option and there is still no scroll bar on the right. I wrote the final output table as: `datatable(mtcars, options(DT.fillContainer = T))`. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just execute `options(DT.fillContainer = T)` as a single command prior to calling `datatable()`. You could also target a single table by `datatable(data, fillContainer = T)`

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer that still didn't work for me unfortunately. Are you using flexdashboard or the original rmarkdown template? Thanks

Comment: Got it to work, I didn't have DT 0.2 installed. Can you leave this as an answer so I can give you credit? Thanks!

Comment: Done. Thanks and happy new year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the latest version of the package `DT` installed (>= 0.2) then scrollbars should be added by default.
If this is not the case, you can edit the option `fillContainer` globally by

```
options(DT.fillContainer = T)
```

If you want to edit only specific tables you can go by

```
datatable(myData, fillContainer = T)
```